# Natural sort / ordering wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: categories, taxonomy, sort, order

I'm using the following code to display an archive dropdown:

```
    wp_dropdown_categories( 'taxonomy=week&hierarchical=1&orderby=name' );
```

However the format of the taxonomy is week-1, week-2 .... week-10, week-11 I need it to be natural orderered as per http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php e.g.

> Week 1
>   Week 2
>   Week ...
>   Week 10
>   Week 11

Currently it's being ordered true alpha e.g.

> Week 1
>   Week 10
>   Week 11
>   Week 2

Not sure what the best way to do this is, any help or thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the best way (at least if you have a lot of tags)

```
add_filter('get_terms_orderby', 'get_terms_orderby_natural_slug',10,2);
wp_dropdown_categories( 'taxonomy=week&hierarchical=1&orderby=slug' );
remove_filter('get_terms_orderby', 'get_terms_orderby_natural_slug');

function get_terms_orderby_natural_slug($orderby, $args){
    $orderby = "SUBSTR({$orderby} FROM 1 FOR 5), CAST(SUBSTR({$orderby} FROM 6) AS UNSIGNED), SUBSTR({$orderby} FROM 6)";
    return $orderby;
}
```

but still this is a way to do that...

Comment: This is an interesting solution, however numbers less than 10 are sorted inverse, e.g. week 9, week 8, week ..., week 1, week 10

Comment: should work now.